# Sony Android - app crashing but running fine on other devices

Tags: android, cross-platform

I developed my first Android app targeting KitKat ( 4-4-2) with minimum SDK being set to 4.1.2 (JellyBean)
Beside standards UI stuff, this apps is dealing with device sensors end using java multithreading ( standard way, no fancy stuff)

it's now running fine on Nexus5 (kitkat) and Wiko5 ( JellyBean ), however I sent the .apk to a friend for testing on Sony Xperia Z and it's crashing...  he si going to send me the device for debugging over tehre...

as I am used to develop w iOS ( one platform, one constructor )  , I'd to know if there is anything to take care before developing for multiple Android devices... additional APIs , should I test locally all these platforms ?

Comment: please tell us your exact problem, what exception do you have? provide us some code.

Comment: i've simmilar experience with sony devices,post your exception i can help you if same issues then.

Answer (score 1):

on windows
try

```
adb logcat -v time > D:\log.txt
```

then open the log.txt by some editer like notepad++, search 'fatal' and lookup crash stack, you can find the reason app crashed. Or Please post it on, so we can help.

Comment: we are bith using Mac, but will run adb

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal world, the Xperia Z should be able to run the app as long as it has the required OS and the sensors your are trying to access. So this looks like something device specific(esp. since it works on your other jellybean device.).

So the way forward would be to look at the logcats.
Also, instead of waiting for the device to reach you, just ask for the logcats - the logs would be the best way to further debug this issue.

Ask your friend to connect the USB to a machine and do the following(assuming android sdk and platform tools are downloaded)

```
adb logcat
```

Better still - copy logs to a text file

```
adb logcat > log.txt
```